# Firefox won't sync after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: firefox, sync

Having upgraded mu Dell Inspiron Mini 10 PP19S with Ubuntu 17.04, I can no longer sync Firefox (54.0 32bit). When I try to sign in to sync it loads a blank page. My desktop also has Ubuntu 17.04 with the same Firefox, and this synced perfectly well UNTIL I disconnected and then tried to sign in again. Now it behaves like my netbook. I assume the reason is the desktop was upgraded from a working install of 16.10 with an already configured firefox until I stupidly disconnected it. (the netbook was clean install so blank Firefox)
I'm assuming this is a 17.04 bug and not a Firefox one. further than that I really don't have a clue.

Comment: Suggest you try these steps. Clear the firefox caches/cookies, try to sync and with the blank page selected, open the [firefox console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console). Maybe it  show any clues to help you.

Comment: [This article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/gnomes-web-adding-firefox-sync-support) could also help you